# Reading height of image with max-width:100% and height:auto in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

If I attach an image to the DOM and log its height like so:

```
$('body').html('<img src="…" width="100" height="100">');
console.log($('img').height());
```

with the following CSS rules declared:

`img {max-width:100%; height:auto}`

Safari returns a height of 0 until a few ms after this code was run. Omitting `height:auto` means the height is returned, but this will cause the image proportions to be distorted in a small container.

Is there a way to force Safari to calculate the height immediately? Chrome does not suffer this problem.

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/gugofen/3/edit?css,js,console,output) - Works in Chrome, not Safari 9.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
var img = document.getElementById('id'); 
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

[doc: clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)

Comment: Thanks for your idea but no this does not work - I've added a demo